# static core dump analysis

Tags: static-analysis, dump

I got a coredump from an unknow binary. I want to retrieve as many information as possible (memory, register, contexte..)

Most of the answers available on the web speak about coredump analysis using the binary that produce it.

I'm looking for a tool able to retrieve some information or a specification/standard about how is a coredump mapped (to do my own tool).

Comment: what format is the dump? ELF? does GDB recognize it?